# Astrophotography without a Star Tracker

Tags: canon-550d, astrophotography

I'm into Astrophotography lately.

I'm using a Canon 550D with kit-lens.

1) I found there was a displacement of stars (obviously) in the picture that I stacked. How to solve this as I don't use a **Star-tracker/telescope** 
2) Also, is it necessary to use [Deep-Sky-Stacker](http://deepskystacker.free.fr/english/index.html) while taking pictures of Milkyway? Is there a good tutorial to follow?

Also, what will the correct exposure settings? I read somewhere about 500/focal-length calculations that I couldn't comprehend.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to PhotoSE. What do you want to photograph? [Tips for shooting planets?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47592/17441) or [How to photograph the Milkyway?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/37997/17441) or is it about [post-processing problems like noise?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/26434/17441) or maybe just [General tips for shooting landscape and stars together?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2136/17441). It is well covered here under tags [tag:stars] and [tag:milky-way] and [tag:astrophotography]. Use search or just click on a tag.

Comment: On the last point, about focal length calculations,  I think maybe you are looking for [the rule of 600](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/30263/1943).