# Is it better to shoot with a higher ISO, or use lower ISO and raise the exposure in post-processing?

Tags: iso, noise

Suppose there are two photos taken in the following scenario:

Scenario 1 - Photo taken using ISO of 3200.

Scenario 2 - Photo taken using ISO of 100.

Both photos are taken in a medium light scenario. The photo in Scenario 2 is quite dark, while the photo taken in Scenario 1 looks good.

From my understanding, higher ISO gives a more grainy photo. So could a photo in scenario 2 (which appears quite dark) be modified in software (e.g. Photoshop) to increase the brightness, and be better than the photo taken with a higher ISO?

Comment: I believe Scenario 1 will yield the better image with less noise - see here:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6615/what-is-iso-on-a-digital-camera

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> From my understanding, higher ISO gives a more grainy photo

I'm afraid your understanding is incorrect. High ISO doesn't necessarily give a more grainy photo as there are other factors involved. In some circumstances it can be the case that lowering ISO increases noise. I did an experiment a while back to prove this:

[image]

What you're seeing is exactly what you describe, one image shot at ISO 1600 unedited, versus the same photo shot at ISO 100, brightened in post to match the first image.

As you can see the ISO 100 image is considerably noisier.

What's going on is that images contain *shot noise* and *read noise*. Shot noise occurs because photons are emitted randomly by lightsources which gives rise to variations in the light hitting each part of the sensor. Read noise occurs as the analogue signal is transferred from the sensor to the [ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter).

What the ISO setting on the camera does is amplify the analogue signal before readout and digitization. When amplifying the signal the shot noise gets amplified too, thus the signal to noise ratio is the same. However the read noise does not get amplified as it happens after amplification. When you shoot at low ISO and brighten the image in software, the photon noise, and the read noise both get amplified, giving a higher level of noise.

---

So why is ISO deemed to determine image noise?

It is true that **the lowest possible level of noise is achieved at the lowest possible ISO with as much light as possible hitting the sensor**.

It is also true that the greatest speed for my car is achieved in fifth gear. But this doesn't mean putting it into fifth with the engine idling will increase my speed. The biggest influence on speed in the throttle position. Gearing just prevents stalling or overrevving the engine.

In the same way the biggest influence on noise is the total amount of light falling on the sensor. But you have to set the ISO to avoid over or under exposing the image.

ISO does not have a direct relationship with noise, if you have a very dim scene with little light falling on the sensor then you will have noise regardless of the ISO setting. Likewise if you have tons of light falling on the sensor you will have very little noise regardless of the ISO setting (though you might have overexposure!)

Another problem with perceptions of noise and ISO is that in any of the automatic shooting modes P/Tv/Av increasing the ISO will cause the camera to alter the shutter speed and/or aperture which results in less light hitting the sensor which means more noise. However in manual mode for a fixed shutter speed and aperture, increasing the ISO *will not result in more noise being present in the image*.

So why does any of this matter? After all if you want the lowest noise your camera can offer you just set it on a tripod, pick ISO 100 and leave the shutter open as long as possible before the image becomes overexposed.

The problem is that thinking about ISO first can lead to misunderstandings. For example when using the above approach in dim light with the aperture wide open, the shutter might max out at 1/30s. People remember the *ISO 100 = lowest noise* part, forget about the need to get a correct exposure (or are mislead by the image on the back of the LCD, which can look well exposed when you're viewing the screen in the dark) and end up underxposing the image, giving more noise than if they'd shot at say ISO 400.

It is just as correct to say **the lowest possible level of noise is achieved when as much light as possible is hitting the sensor (without overexposing the image) and the ISO is as high as possible (without overexposing the image)**. In most cases the highest ISO possible will be 100.

Thinking about the level of light first, then the ISO avoids pitfalls when there is some limit to how much light you can get onto the sensor during the exposure.

---

There are other minsunderstandings that originate from thinking about ISO as the primary factor that determines noise. One such misunderstanding relates to a camera's base (minimum native) ISO. Someone with a camera Y whose base ISO is 200 might think "since ISO 200 gets me the cleanest images, wouldn't it be great to have ISO 50 like camera X". Now it may be the case that camera Y has a sensor with fantastic quantum efficiency, and very good microlenses meaning it is very efficient at capturing light, hence images become overexposed quickly, leading to a high base ISO. Camera X might have a much older sensor with poor QE, no microlenses and low fill factor. It wastes a lot of light and thus requires longer exposures. It also produces images with the same level of noise at ISO 50 as Y does at ISO 200. Just because the number is lower doesn't mean it's better.

Finally thinking about light first helps explain "ISO less" sensors, such as the latest batch of Sony sensors found in cameras like the Pentax K5 or Nikon D800. The read noise is so low that it doesn't make any difference if you amplify the signal prior to readout, meaning that you can get comparable results at many different ISO settings, proving that ISO isn't responsible for image noise.

---

My preferred method of shooting is in manual mode with auto-ISO. This allows me to select the depth of field and amount of motion blur that I want/can tolerate in the image, and then have the camera minimise noise for me.

Comment: Nothing like a simple test to disprove hours of speculation! +1!  Also, now that I have auto-ISO in M, I hardly leave it. Greatest advancement in my recent body upgrade, along with silky ISO 1600 :)

Comment: "The reason for the association between high ISO and noise..." Matt, that's not exactly correct, and you know it. If the image can be *correctly* exposed at a lower ISO (and let's assume an integral multiple of the camera's base ISO to get poor implementations out of the way), it will have both lower noise (resulting from a more statistically valid sampling of the light—a probabilistic phenomenon—or reduced shot noise if you prefer) and a higher dynamic range. In your example, a still life, the ISO 100 exposure could easily have been 1/2s, resulting in less noise than the ISO 1600 exposure.

Comment: (cont'd) I'm not taking issue with the overall statement—that exposing correctly will be better than "fixing in post"—it's just that you keep leaving out the part where you should say that *correct exposures* at lower ISO values (at least until the base ISO is hit) will result in lower noise than *equally well-exposed* shots at higher ISOs.

Comment: Stan has nailed it. You get the lowest apparent noise with the highest possible signal to noise ratio and pixel saturation. Sometimes you have no option but to select an aperture and shutter speed, and push ISO as high as you can without clipping a that aperture and shutter speed...but generally speaking using the lowest ISO setting while still getting a proper exposure will result in the cleanest images. If you have the ability to expose for several seconds, or use an ultra wide aperture, while pushing the exposure to the right, at ISO 100...then do so. You'll have a cleaner image.

Comment: In the astrophotography world, people are using Canon DSLRs extensively and have split the hairs on the ISO question.  Craig Stark has run the numbers on some Canon product and published a detailed analysis of linearity of data from these cameras: Profiling the Long-Exposure Performance of a Canon DSLR (July 2, 2012, Cloudy Nights)  http://www.stark-labs.com/craig/resources/Articles-&-Reviews/CanonLinearity.pdf  In a nutshell, he says that Canon is modifying the dark signal before it hits the raw file and that settings above ISO 400 are of limited value.

Comment: @jrista Max SNR is indeed achieved at min ISO with as much light as possible hitting the sensor. You say **"using the lowest ISO setting while still getting a proper exposure will result in the cleanest images"**, the problem I have with this is that it places the emphasis on ISO. The approach of "set ISO to 100 and then make sure the image is properly exposed" will guarantee the cleanest images **if there is enough light**, but what happens when the shutter maxes out at 1/30s is people remember the ISO=100 bit and forget the second part, leading to increased noise. I've seen it happen.

Comment: ...continued... Whereas, approaching the problem from the other direction: **"get as much light as possible onto the sensor without clipping, then set the ISO to make sure the image is properly exposed"** is a methodology that guarantees the cleanest images **in all possible scenarios**. Thinking about amount of light first and then ISO avoids any trap, and prevents the type of confusion that resulted in this question being asked.

Comment: @StanRogers I've rewritten that whole section, hopefully it makes more sense and is less ambiguous now.

Comment: I am not saying always use ISO 100. I am saying push the histogram as far to the right as you can with shutter and aperture, then use the LOWEST ISO setting that gets the right-hand ends of the RGB histograms into the right-most histogram box. I guess whenever you post answers like this, it sounds like you are telling people to use the highest ISO setting possible, and I just want people to be clear...they should still be aiming to use the **lowest ISO** that maximizes the signal without clipping. If someone has the option of increasing exposure time or is ok with a faster aperture...

Comment: ...using those options FIRST is better than increasing ISO. A wider aperture or a longer shutter are not always possible in all forms of photography, however there are many forms of photography where it is possible to increase shutter speed to maximize SNR. Your example with the books is an ideal case...it is handy as a ready-made demonstration of auto-exposure in post ISO 100 vs. 1600...but you could have easily lengthened the exposure in that still-life scene and the ISO 100 image would have been better than the ISO 1600 image. You don't adequately explain that, and I think it is confusing.

Comment: @smigol: As far as I can tell, that article is written rather specifically from the standpoint of astrophotography, and the elimination of dark current noise. Multi-minute exposures at higher ISO don't generally occur in any other form of photography...in most cases, the purpose of using a higher ISO is to achieve a **faster** shutter speed, meaning exposure times will usually be short, and therefor not encounter the long-exposure dark current issues. Broadly applying Craig's claims to all photography is invalid, as his context was set to astrophotography on the first page of the paper.

Comment: Absolutely it's a specialized case.  The important thing to note is that Canon is doing noise reduction at the raw, creating part of the different performance of the ISO levels.  Thus, the example given may not be identical and it may not be as strictly controlled as originally thought.  Still, this is a corner case.

Comment: @smigol In that document, Craig has totally neglected readout noise. He suggests going beyond ISO 400 is worthless because discretisation error from counting single electrons is about the same as quantisation error from the A-D converter. However increasing ISO continues to be useful until discretisation error from electron counting is bigger than readout noise ( in terms of its standard deviation). From the bottom left figure on p3 of Craig's document it looks like the readout noise is about 10 A-D counts (sqrt of variance at 0 exposure) so ISO increases up to about 4000 would be useful.

Comment: Hi, Matt! Thanks for your detailed explanation and post in this thread. Do you have an updated link to the tests you'd done? I'm getting a 404 when I click.

Answer (score 9):

If the iso 3200 is not overexposed then the iso 100 is very dark, not just quite dark. In 8bit range it would go between 0 and 15 pixel values, so very noisy, and the iso 3200 would be quite fine, except in dark regions.

These images are ISOs 200,400,800,1600 from left to right on an old Canon 400D where high iso was known to be bad. But still the ISO 1600 is the best.

[image: iso 200-1600]
[Larger](http://sequoiagrove.dk/images/cameraisotest/isotest_noflash.jpg)

Indeed, the best way to lower noise is by adding light to teh sensor, through settings or by adding light to the scene. These operations come with a cost: adding light **changes the scene** we want to capture, adding light through exposure time risks **motion blur** which can be *worse* than the noise, and opening the iris (if possible) **decrease the DOF** and makes the **lens soft**, and maybe even add some **fringing**.

Here I added flash, iso 200-800 (1600 would overexpose):

[image: flash]
[Larger](http://sequoiagrove.dk/images/cameraisotest/isotest_flash1_4.jpg)

Here we see that now there is enough light to make a low noise image in all cases - especially notice that going up in iso still doesn't make it noisier. **Lack of light** makes it noisy, not high iso.

In conclusion, light > iso, but higher iso != your enemy; it is your friend when the light fails you.

Answer (score 8):

Formally, it is better to go with higher ISO, as long as higher ISO is implemented the way it is supposed to be implemented: as higher gain setting for the internal analog signal amplifier in the camera, i.e. signal amplifier that works in the signal *before* it gets converted to discrete digital form.

From the purely mathematical point of view, internal amplifier also "multiplies" the signal, just like "Exposure" slider in some post-processing software does. However, the multiplication is performed on the *analog* side of the processing flow, before the signal is converted to digital form. This precludes any rounding errors that are invariably introduced when the multiplication (or virtually any other image value transformation) is performed on the discrete digitized values.

Of course, in order for all this to work, your camera must implement the ISO setting specifically by adjusting the gain of the internal analog amplifier. Cheaper digital cameras might implement "fake" ISO settings by keeping the amplifier gain constant and multiplying the image data after it was converted to digital form. Such implementation will offer absolutely no meaningful benefits over what you can do in post-processing. It is precisely the same thing as the "Exposure" slider in post-processing software.

Meanwhile, many modern SLR cameras implement majority of their ISO settings by adjusting the amplifier gain, while "simulating" the most extreme ISO settings (the highest and/or the lowest) by digital multiplication. There's no point in using such simulated ISO values for the reasons mentioned above. Some cameras might implement "standard" ISO values (lie 100, 200, 400, 800 etc) by adjusting the amplifier gain, while simulating fractional ISO values by digital multiplication from the nearest "standard" ISO value. Again, there's no point in using such simulated ISO values.

Comment: My Canon 70D seems (via Rawdigger) to have a range of about 12000 discrete values for each sample. The size of the pixels indicates that a well capacity is areound 23000, if memory serves. IAC, about double.  This implies that the ISO setting has (a small) effect on how the photon counts are mapped to sample values. If the sample were 15 bits (not 14) then it could return all the collected information always. As is, it must have *at least* a high/low setting that controls whether to take the dim half or cut the precision in half. otherwise, is it analog gain or digital scaling?

Comment: A little caveat, current ISO standard doesn't suggest any preferred methods of ISO speed implementation. Analogue implementation results in lower ratio of 'transport noise' to signal because 'transport noise' (the noise on the way to ADC) is pretty much constant while signal is boosted. For sensors with low read noise analogue implementation becomes progressively irrelevant in terms of noise reduction, making the behavior of all ISO speed settings very close to simulated.

Answer (score 3):

To correct your statement a little,

> "A higher ISO will produce a more grainy image **at standard exposure**."

The ISO used has no impact on the light entering the camera or the sensitivity of the sensor to light.  A certain amount of signal must be registered to mute out the noise that is inherent in the system.  At a high ISO, the sensor processes a smaller amount of light as more light and thus develops an image faster, but has more noise.

That same image, taken with a lower ISO, but at the same speed will still have the same amount of noise, but as Matt Grum points out, the digital conversion will likely amplify the noise and thus make a worse overall image as the levels going in will be so low when still in analog form.

The reason that there is less noise at standard exposure is that the additional time that light is collected by the sensor results in more signal compared to the relatively constant amount of noise.

Basically you get noise from both power fluctuations in the camera and in noise from the image sensor if you use a lower ISO and don't do a standard exposure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a tripod and you can, use low ISO. If you cannot use a tripod, increase the ISO because grainy images are better than shaked ones. A very dark picture cannot be recovered (as a burned one) once it gets "full dark areas" because there is nothing to recover (no details). So, if you can see things through your viewfinder and after taking the photo you still have details, it's OK. Also, check the histogram.

Comment: This is not a good advice, see @Matt Grumm's answer for details.

Comment: To clarify, the user was not asking if he should use a longer exposure on a higher ISO, he was asking if the same exposure time would be better artificially raised or if using a higher ISO would be better.  Matt Grum's answer is the correct one for the question asked.

Comment: If you can read the full answer: `A very dark picture cannot be recovered (as a burned one) once it gets "full dark areas" because there is nothing to recover (no details)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the camera.  Increasing the ISO boosts the signal from the sensor, and this is different than brightening the image in post. High ISO can be thought of as a hardware boost while brightening in post can be thought of as a software boost.

Increasing ISO might result in less noise, it might not, compared to post processing brightening. Most cameras boost the signal only up to a point (400 to 1000 ISO or so) and achieve effective ISO increases on top of that by software manipulation.  Again, at what point this happens varies by camera model.

You'd have to test your specific camera model to know how the effects of high ISO and PP brightening differ.

In any case, you want a *good* exposure, that is you want raw data with the most useful information in it, and the [expose to the right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposing_to_the_right) technique is usually a good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a digital camera here.  If at equal exposure, quality could be improved by lowering the ISO value and digitally amplifying the signal, why would the camera not do it by itself?  Where would be the point in artificially making the image worse than it can be?

With film, you could argue that similar techniques could make some sense since exposure and lab processing are two different stages controlled by different actors, and if you had control over both actors rather than just one, you could improve results in a manner that you couldn't by only controlling exposure.

But the digital photograph produced in the camera is completely under control of the camera.  If underexposing and then amplifying the result digitally would be the best way forward, that is how ISO would be *implemented* (in fact, "ISO invariant" sensors like newer Sony Exmor sensors do it in that manner; but with numerous other/older/smaller sensors the circuitry in the analog domain can do a better job when it anticipates lower exposure).