# Looking for best settings for D7200 for indoor basketball game

Tags: indoor, nikon-d7200

Looking for best settings for D7200 for indoor kids basketball game. I will be shooting from the bleachers. Want to make sure the lighting is right and that the action is clear. I usually shoot shutter priority outside photos..

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE, feel free to take the [tour]! Have you checked previous questions on the [topic of indoor sports](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports+indoor)? Like [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65220/how-to-photograph-low-light-indoor-sport)? Or [this one on hockey](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87485/9161)? And here's one on [volleyball](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114287/9161). If these don't answer your question, please [edit] your question to include why, this enables people to provide you better answers.

Comment: The best settings for any shooting scenario are highly dependent upon the specific scene lighting. I don't use the same settings in two different gyms with two different types of lighting with different brightness, color temperature, and CRI.

Comment: Settings are also highly dependent upon your lens' maximum aperture at the focal lengths you're using. You can't use the same settings with a 70-300mm f/4-5.6 variable aperture zoom as you can use with a 70-200mm f/2.8 constant aperture zoom or even a 135mm f/2 prime.

Comment: Just as a ballpark, a gone-from-the-internet reference that I saved years ago listed a bunch of situations and an estimate of the light value. "Indoor sports" was listed as EV 7, which, at f/2.8 and a shutter speed of 1/500 (for the action), would necessitate an ISO setting of 3200. I know others here have more experience shooting sports than I do, but that's roughly what you're dealing with. A local school gym could even be 1 or 2 EV darker than that.

Answer (score 3):

My settings for fast moving objects are:

- shutter priority
- shutter speed 1/500 (tune it for your case, closest moving objects need faster speed)
- Auto ISO (this will introduce noise but the case is have noisy photo or do not have it at all)
- Usually I set focal points in group around the center or activate all focal points

Depend of the lens you may want to set image stabilization to be activated when you take the photo (if your lens support it).

P.S. Probably you will want to limit the maximum ISO. This can be done in [ISO sensitivity settings](https://imaging.nikon.com/support/digitutor/d7200/functions/autoisocontrol.html) menu.

P.P.S. And will be wise to take photos in RAW format. Postprocessing software can deal better with noise and you can select how much.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be nice to know what lens will you be using, more specifically whats the maximum aperature? And we cant possibly give you the exact settings since we dont know the lightning conditions in the sports hall...

Since the lightning is fixed and even through the whole court I'd suggest having camera on manual mode with fixed shutterspeed so you dont get any blurry shots... I shoot indor basketball at 1/1000s at F2.8 ISO 3200... But this can vary from the lightning of the sports hall... start with some fixed setting and during warmup take some shots and adjust settings acordingly